# ggplot2: several plots per single facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I want to make plot like in picture using ggplot2 and facets. As always there is grouped data and each group is mapped to facet. Tricky part is that I want single facet to consist of three independent plots (not layers): regression line, residuals, QQ-plot.

[link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pzLK.jpg)

Chill out with downvote warfare. Here is code

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>% 
group_by(Species) %>% 
nest %>%
mutate(mod = map(data, ~lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, .))) %>%
mutate(
    tidy = map(mod, broom::tidy),
    glance = map(mod, broom::glance),
    augment = map(mod, broom::augment)
) -> models

df <- models %>% select(Species, augment) %>% unnest

df %>% print

ggplot() +
geom_count(data=df, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour = Species), alpha=0.7) +
geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=.fitted), alpha=0.7, color="black", shape='x', size=5) +
geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=.resid, colour=Species), alpha=0.2) +
stat_qq(data=df, aes(sample=.resid, colour=Species), distribution=qnorm, alpha=0.2) +
facet_wrap(~Species, scales = "free") +
theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
      legend.direction = "vertical")
```

Resulting plot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2BGy.png)

As you can see plots are overlapping on each facet. Sad! Meanwhile I want "complex" facet, where each facet contains three independent plots.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example and what have you tried so far. And please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Because the types of information in each plot are so different, you're going to need to make three plots and bind them together.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)
library(purrr)
library(gridExtra)

iris.lm <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length*Species, iris)

p1 <- ggplot(augment(iris.lm), aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  theme_classic() + guides(color = F) + 
  labs(title = "Regression") +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(color = "black")) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", colour = "black") + geom_point(shape = 1) +
  facet_grid(Species~.)

p2 <- ggplot(augment(iris.lm), aes(.fitted, .resid, color = Species)) + 
  theme_classic() + guides(color = F) +
  labs(x = "Fitted values", y = "Residuals") +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(color = "black")) +
  stat_smooth(se = F, span = 1, colour = "black") + geom_point(shape = 1) +
  facet_grid(Species~.)

p3 <- ggplot(augment(iris.lm), aes(sample = .resid/.sigma, color = Species)) + 
  theme_classic() + theme(panel.background = element_rect(color = "black")) +
  labs(x = "Theoretical quantiles", y = "Standardized residuals", title = "Q-Q") +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, color = "black") +
  stat_qq(distribution = qnorm, shape = 1) + 
  facet_grid(Species~.)

p <- list(p1, p2, p3) %>% purrr::map(~ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(.)))

cbind.gtable(p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]) %>% grid.arrange()
```

[image]

To demonstrate what wrangling the data around to do it all in one `ggplot` call looks like, here's another crack at it. This is an inferior solution, since you have to call `geom_blank` with the modified data to get uniform scales within plot type, and you can't label the plots with their axes properly.

[image]

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


iris.lm <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length*Species, iris)

data_frame(type = factor(c("Regression", "F vs R", "Q-Q"), 
                         levels = c("Regression", "F vs R", "Q-Q"))) %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  do(augment(iris.lm)) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(yval = case_when(
    type == "Regression" ~ Sepal.Width,
    type == "F vs R" ~ .resid,
    type == "Q-Q" ~ .resid/.sigma
                         ),
         xval = case_when(
    type == "Regression" ~ Sepal.Length,
    type == "F vs R" ~ .fitted,
    type == "Q-Q" ~ qnorm(ppoints(length(.resid)))[order(order(.resid/.sigma))]
                         ),
    yval.sm = case_when(
      type == "Regression" ~ .fitted,
      type == "F vs R" ~ loess(.resid ~ .fitted, span = 1)$fitted,
      type == "Q-Q" ~ xval
    )) %>% {
  ggplot(data = ., aes(xval, yval, color = Species)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~interaction(type, Species, sep = ": "), scales = "free") + 
  geom_line(aes(xval, yval.sm), colour = "black") + 
  geom_blank(data = . %>% ungroup() %>% select(-Species) %>% 
               mutate(Species = iris %>% select(Species) %>% distinct()) %>%
               unnest(), 
             aes(xval, yval)) +
  labs(x = "Sepal.Length: actual values, fitted values, theoretical quantiles",
       y = "Sepal.Width: actual values, residuals, standardized residuals")}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. This is really unfortunate if facet_wrap cannot work here. My idea was that ggplot2 is powerful enough to produce compound plot for each group and stick them together in one big plot. All these behind the scene of facet_wrap.

Comment: @MatrixNorm `facet_wrap` does what it's intended to do: produce small multiples for comparing between groups. That's why each column of the plot is nice and tidy. It's not intended for producing multiple types of plots. You could fight with it and eventually get them all into one single `ggplot` call, but it would not be the "tidy" way to do it.

Comment: @MatrixNorm, I updated my code to show you what an all-in-one would have to look like. `ggplot` has to be told what to put in which panel.

Comment: @MatrixNorm, if you just want the easy way out, check out https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_lm.html